# Почему не работает функция Ord()?

Tags: функции, vb.net

```
Function getNumOfSym(ch As Char)
        Return ord(ch)
    End Function
```

VB не знает такой функции, хотя раньше я ей пользовался. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что `VB` и `VB.NET` это разные вещи.
Используйте функцию `Asc`

```
Function getNumOfSym(ch As Char)
    Return Asc(ch)
End Function
```